# how to unset session without destroying?

Tags: php, session

How to Unset a session variable without destroying it so it can be used again

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
session_start();

     if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
      {
        if(isset($_POST['logout'])){

          session_unset();
          unset($_SESSION['username']);
          unset($_SESSION['password']);
          header('location:index.php');
        }

        if(isset($_POST['unset'])){
          session_destroy();
          header('location:registration.php');
        }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <h1>Welcome</h1>

      <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout" class="btn btn-danger">
      <input type="submit" name="unset" value="remove user" class="btn btn-danger">

      </form>    


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
}
else{
  echo "not login";
}
?>
```

Here on logout button , just want to unset the session variables so the session variables can be used again in login.php.

PS: I dont want to use Database.

Comment: $_SESSION['username']='' is the only option

Comment: but after unsetting how to get the value back?

Comment: I don't see the issue in your php? Are the sessions not being unset?

Answer (score 0):

You can either

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_POST['unset'])){
         //removes all the current variables in the 
         //session and re-initializes them to nothing or null
         $_SESSION = array();

         //or
         //for each variable in your session unset like - to remove single values.
         unset($_SESSION["username"]);
     }
?>
```